# Getting NFT metadata in polkadotjs with typescript

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

I'm trying to call `api.query.nfts.itemMetaDataOf<type>(collection_id, token_id);` via typescript and polkadotjs.

It's not clear which type I'm supposed to use for the response. At least I can't find any suitable type in @polkadot/types-codec.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually [generate](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen#generating) the types of your chain using `typegen`. You have to point to the WS address of your chain to download the metadata, and derive custom types from it. Here is the example [project](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/tree/master/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen).

In your case, it would probably look like this (after you have generated custom types):

```
import { PalletNftsItemMetadata } from "./lookup";

let itemMetadata = await api.query.nfts.itemMetadataOf<PalletNftsItemMetadata>(
  collection_id,
  token_id
);
```

Comment: That works indeed. The only issue I have is that, when trying to import the type, I get the error: 
```
Module '"../../interfaces/lookup"' has no exported member 'PalletNftsItemMetadata'. Did you mean to use 'import PalletNftsItemMetadata from "../../interfaces/lookup"' instead?
```

It's strange, because PalletNftsItemMetadata is under export default.

Comment: yeah, it could be the case. Did you also include the new types/interfaces in the `tsconfig.json`? If you have included them, they should be available from normal `@polkadot/types` package

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions and added paths to tsconfig.json:

"paths": {
      // this is the package name we use (in the interface imports, --package for generators)
      "incentiverse/*": ["./src/*"],
      // here we replace the @polkadot/api augmentation with our own, generated from chain
      "@polkadot/api/augment": ["./src/interfaces/augment-api.ts"],
      // replace the augmented types with our own, as generated from definitions
      "@polkadot/types/augment": ["./src/interfaces/augment-types.ts"]
    }

Comment: Also trying to import as `import type { PalletNftsItemMetadata } from '@polkadot/types';` results in the same no exported member error.